# AJAX call returns results, but in a blank page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

There are a couple of questions that are somewhat similar to this, but I haven't been able to get their solutions to work for me.

Basically, I am making an AJAX call that is working properly--the result is coming back through. The issue is that instead of processing the result, the result-array is printed back to the screen (and deletes everything else). Clearly, it is not handling the incoming result properly, but I'm not sure why.

This is the form being sent:

```
<form class="removeAndApply" method="post" action="">
    …hidden inputs...
    <button type="submit">Use</button>
</form>
```

The PHP that is processing the AJAX:

```
case "removeAndApply_PromoCode":
    …Get data from $_POST….
    …process stuff...
    $response = …..;
    $finalPrice = ….;

    $dataArray = array('response'=>$response, 'finalPrice'=>$finalPrice);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode( $dataArray );
    exit();
    break;
```

Here is a sample result text, as printed on my screen during failure:
`{"response":{"Col1":"13","0":"13","Col2":"PC2","1":"PC2","Col3":"1","2":"1","Col4":"45.89","3":"45.89","col5":null,"4":null,"Col6":"1","5":"1"},"finalPrice":0}`

And this is the javascript function that is supposed to handle it:

```
$('.removeAndApply').ajaxForm({url: this.href, type:'post',
    data: this.serialize,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        alert("asdf");
    } 
 });
```

Thanks.

Comment: do **console.log(data);** in your success function and look at the console. whats being returned?

Comment: Nothing--I suspect it fails before ever entering the success function

Comment: so something the way your encoding the array can be wrong.. what happens if you remove exit()?

Comment: You sure this.href holds the correct url ? since this is a form

Comment: @JelleKeizer-Yeah…plus, all my other AJAX calls are using it too (so I know that's not the error). Also, the response IS being returned correctly…so it's being sent to the right place.

@alda1234 - It does the same blank-page with result printed on it, except with more text (because there's no 'exit()' stopping it).

Comment: This problem appears when you have a `document.write()` call during the ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in HTML button type attribute. When you have a `<button type="submit">` in `<form>` and you clicked it. The form submits, request is sent to the server, browser opening the new response in new document.

If you make some changes:

HTML:

```
<form class="removeAndApply" method="post" action="">
    …hidden inputs...
    <button type="button" id="submit-form">Use</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#submit-form').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: window.location.href,
    data: $('.removeAndApply').serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {...},
    error: function(err) {...}
  });
});
```

Everything should be fine.

Comment: Or you have to `preventDefault()` in `onclick` handler.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably better suited for a comment, but I don't have enough rep for that, so:

This is the type of behavior you'd see if you don't bind the ajax form functionality to that form... the button submits the form as normal and you just see plain json coming from the server as a response to the (non-ajax) post.  Are you sure that ajaxForm() statement is being executed?